# Detect unnecessary explicit relation between nodes

Tags: cypher, redisgraph

I have group node structure where a node inherits permissions from previous node

```
Manager ---Implies---> PowerUser ---Implies---> User
```

But the structure is not clean and sometimes i have 2 edges from **manager**
to **poweruser** and again to **user** which is already implied by **poweruser**

```
Manager ---Implies---> PowerUser ---Implies---> User
        ---Implies----------------------------> User
```

How can i query nodes to dectect that i already have a implicit relation and that i don't need the extra explicit relation

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `PowerUser` is a label in your structure. You can write a variable-length traversal [1] that considers paths of any length so long as this label appears somewhere:

`MATCH (entity)-[*0..]->(:PowerUser)`

Would be the broadest traversal to accomplish this, matching any node connected to the `PowerUser` label by 0 or more edges.

Given that `PowerUser` is a permission, however, it seems like a more appropriate design would be to treat it as a property. Since Cypher is schema-less, properties are not scoped to specific labels, so it can be set and filtered on nodes with the `Manager` or `User` labels. This approach would allow more succinct expressions like:

`MATCH (entity {PowerUser: true})-[]->()`

If this doesn't match your use case, feel free to provide more details about your graph structure!

1. https://oss.redislabs.com/redisgraph/commands/#variable-length-relationships